# how to create a custom master page in sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I would like to change the two default master pages and customize a new master page.But I can't understand how to do it.Please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

The below Article may help you to understand the Master page and customization

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/portal-branding

Answer (score 0):

It is highly recommended that you'd don't customize master pages in SharePoint Online. This guidance is available in the docs titled [Branding guidance for SharePoint Online portals](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/portal-branding).

Relevant bit:

"What not to do...Implement by default your custom branding by using custom master pages."

The docs go on to recommend strategies, including custom CSS and JavaScript.